# How to display row details on click from WebGrid MVC4 using JQuery, AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC3. I'm currently building a site to display a list of Faxes that we received. I have the model, controller and the view working correctly. I also have the row selection enabled. The problem that I'm experiencing is in displaying the details of the data of the selected row. I'm only showing a few elements of the database table, but the model contains a lot more. How can I make rest of the data display on a partial page or a separate div when I click on a row? I tried using GetSelectLink on a column, and used grid.HasSelection to display the details, but this requires the user to only click on that particular column value. I want to be able to click anywhere on the row to make the data details appear. Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show us your code please - as this would be a good starting point for us.
You'll need to show Controller/model and view code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Created a function in controller that returned JSON object; did rest of the stuff in Jquery. Apparently, the json and jquery stuff was needed to be in the view so razor can parse the url.

Answer (score -1):

```
// for display edit word in each row        
grid.Column("Edit", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink("Edit")),             
   ....        
// On Edit Click         
@if (grid.HasSelection)        
{        
    TestSite.Models.News nws = new TestSite.Models.News();          
    nws = (TestSite.Models.News)grid.Rows[grid.SelectedIndex].Value;           
    // for getting value         
    <b>First Name</b> @nwz.Id<br />                                               
       ....                      
}
```